# Use XSL and Display Data Vertically in CSV File

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xslt-2.0

### Data Source

I am trying to take the following XML structure, and transform it into a CSV file with XSL.

```
<Root>
  <Row>
    <Employee>Harry</Employee>
    <Employees_Manager_1>Ron</Employees_Manager_1>
    <Employees_Manager_2>Hermione</Employees_Manager_2>
    <Employees_Manager_3>Ginni</Employees_Manager_3>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Employee>Ross</Employee>
    <Employees_Manager_1>Emma</Employees_Manager_1>
    <Employees_Manager_2>Monica</Employees_Manager_2>
    <Employees_Manager_3>Rachel</Employees_Manager_3>
  </Row>
</Root>
```

### Desired Output in CSV

```
    Harry,Ron,
    Harry,Hermione,
    Harry,Ginni,
    Ross,Emma,
    Ross,Monica,
    Ross,Rachel,
```

### Failed Attempt

I am a beginner in XML/XSL, and so far I only know how to use the following:

```
<xsl:template match="Root">
  <xsl:for-each select="Row">
    <xsl:value-of select="Employee"/>
    <text>,</text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Employees_Manager_1"/>
    <text>,</text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Employees_Manager_2"/>
    <text>,</text>
    <xsl:value-of select="Employees_Manager_3"/>
    <text>,</text>
    <endTag>&#xD;&#xA;</endTag>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I am getting this result:

```
    Harry, Ron, Hermione, Ginni,
    Ross, Emma, Monica, Rachel,
```

### Question

Is there a way to get my desired output with XSL? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 2/3, to map XML to CSV, I usually apply-templates to the elements supposed to be mapped to a line in the CSV and then output any items for each line using `xsl:value-of` with a `separator` attribute:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Root/Row/(* except Employee)"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Row/*">
      <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::Employee, ." separator=","/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPJ8LV6

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="Root">
        <xsl:for-each select="Row">
            <xsl:value-of select="Employee"/>
            <text>,</text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Employees_Manager_1"/>
            <text>,</text>
            <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Employee"/>
            <text>,</text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Employees_Manager_2"/>
            <text>,</text>
            <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Employee"/>
            <text>,</text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Employees_Manager_3"/>
            <text>,</text>
            <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**DEMO:** https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1PuP2

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Duh, now looking at your solution it seemed so obvious. Thanks again!